# How late are restaurants open until in Italy? (Bologna specifically)

Tags: food-and-drink, italy, late-arrival, bologna

I am heading to Los Angeles in three weeks but I have an 8 hour layover in Bologna Italy. Unfortunately this layover is  from midnight-8am. Is it worth it to leave the airport in search of some traditional bolognese Italian food or will everything be closed?

Comment: Restaurants are likely to be closed. Fast-food joints maybe not. I doubt you'll find typical Bolognese Italian food between midnight and 8am.

Comment: I can attest that there are some wonderful places with home-style Italian cooking on the Autostrada near Bologna (among other places). Many open 24/7. Presumably you'll have to arrange a taxi to/from. I love them. Check http://www.saveur.com/article/blog/a-day-of-autogrills-eating-through-italys-rest-stops for a blog report. And your researching phrase is "Autostrada Autogrill Bologna".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four years later, a local writes `;)` I answer in covid time (now we are under curfew 10pm to 5am) but what I write applies in general.

**Short answer: no**, no traditional food in Bologna after midnight.

Proper restaurants close at 10.30pm or 11pm and, yes, very possibly the kitchen closes sooner. After midnight not even kiosks are reliable, out of the "nightlife area" within the city center.

I found [some of the page linked in the other answer on a web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20141218213110/http://www.bolognawelcome.com/en/nightlife/eating-drinking/late-opening-restaurants/). Some of the venues here listed are discos, pubs or bars. *Altotasso* is a late night drink place, not really a late night food place; after a certain hour in the evening, you will only get sandwiches and snacks. *Arterìa* is great to "meet new people", not really to eat something.

If you are ok with pizzas and bakery products, [*Gingio*](https://goo.gl/maps/VCa1Xt23iqjmCPLg6) is next to the two towers, only closes 6am to 9am and has saved many lives.

The latest night *tagliatelle* that you can find in town are probably served at [*Dragon Pub*](https://g.page/thedragonpub) in via della Repubblica. Here you can find proper quality meals with first and second courses...say till 1am or 2am.

Among the proper restaurants, [*Il Rosso*](https://goo.gl/maps/yyNpcU4tb6yzP2Fy5) claims to close at 11pm but, I bet, they would serve you food at 10.45pm.

Answer (score -1):

I just googled and found [Late Opening Restaurants in Bologna](http://www.bolognawelcome.com/en/nightlife/eating-drinking/late-opening-restaurants/search/servizi_19/lingua_en/page_0/) and several that I saw on that site listed being open to 3 or 4AM.   But I'm not a local, so who actually knows?

While doing my google search I also saw someone mention that the shops in the airport shutdown overnight - so you may be forced to get out if you want any refreshments anyway.

Comment: I think it should be manageable to make it to one of the places listed if planned ahead of time with backups. Thanks for the help i saw the notice about the airport as well but i also saw 24/7 cafes there so as you said who knows.

Comment: I am honestly not sure if this answer is particularly helpful. Even if some of the premises on the list you are linking to are actually open late (some however close as early as 10pm), I would expect that most of the places close their kitchen long before the listed closing hours.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The list does prove that there are restaurants that claim to stay open really late. So in that respect I think it does provide useful and relevant information.

Comment: Ideally a native of Bologna would post of a specific location that they frequent but I am not so optimistic that would occur. Some of the links did indeed list the kitchen closing hours specifically so in that regard it is really helpful. Now as to if they are reliable or not that's another question.Generally my experience in Europe is that hours posted online aren't maintained as well as in the US.

Comment: @PeterM, I'm not downvoting your answer, but emphatically suggest you provide more substance to your answers. The OP could flag a taxi at the airport and get more info than you provided. And EVERY metropolitan local in Europe has something open all night!  Please be helpful and informative in your answers.

Comment: @GayotFow This is branching into discussion rather than comments, but short of moving to Bologna I can't really give an answer with more substance.

Comment: @PeterM, the best strategy to use when you cannot give an answer with more substance is to *abstain*. But as mentioned, I'm not down voting, but I did flag up your answer for review by the higher ups if that's of any use.

Comment: @GayotFow From my point of view my answer did have substance in it, and the OP agreed with me by selecting it.  The dearth of other answers also tends to substantiate the quality of my answer.  As for the down voting, people do what people do - although in this case I find it amusing.

Comment: @sonhu I will by this morning, despite 4 years later :)